# Как быть с реестром (пишет в Wow6432Node)?

Tags: c++, реестр

Пишу программку, которая работает с реестром.

Записываю данные сюда: "Software\my-firm". Раньше так и писало. Теперь пишет в "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\my-firm". Это перенаправление WOW64.

Что произошло - не пойму даже... Ничего такого не делал. Как это отключить?

Comment: а есть ли смысл в отключении, если сие перенаправление прозрачно как для пользователя так и для разработчика? Если вы не планируете создание двух (х32 и х64) версий программы, которые используют одни и те же настройки, то имхо оставьте как есть.

Answer (score 3):

В 64-битных Windows реестр разделяется на два логических "подреестра" прозрачно для пользователя(программиста) - для 32-битных программ и 64-битных программ. Очевидно, просто перекомпилируйте свое приложение под x64. Либо используйте  [RegDisableReflectionKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724858(v=vs.85).aspx) из WinAPI.

[Подробнее.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Я и так компилирую Win32 приложение

Comment: перенаправления wow64, имеют место быть вроде когда на 64-разрядной платформе используется 32 разрядное приложение. Так что скомпилировать скорее тогда наоборот надо под х64.

Comment: @sitev_ru ^^^^^

Comment: @teran, вы абсолютно правы, под Win64, конечно же - обновил ответ

Comment: @PavelMayorov автор поста всегда видит все уведомления.

Comment: @PavelMayorov если я написал комментарий к ответу с указанием ошибки в нем, дак как вы думаете я кому его писал, автору ответа, или автору вопроса?

Comment: @teran но автору вопроса тоже сказать надо было.